# Why would FlightAware show this meandering flight path?

Tags: flight-path, online-tracking, flight-tracking

Today's BA219 from LHR to DEN (2018-03-20) appeared to fly 5 zigzags just before and over the Hudson Bay in Canada at around 18:15z. Prior to that, its flight path matched its planned route very closely.

I know that congestion avoidance can sometimes lead to flights being asked to fly doglegs (as in [Why did this plane fly in a zigzag pattern?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/29808)), but this flight was still 3 hours from its destination and still exceeding planned speed when it appeared to fly zigzags. I don't see any weather issues on radar at the time.

After the zigzags seen in the FlightAware capture, the flight track straightened up and flew parallel to its planned route. This appears to be a track data problem, not the actual plane's path.

[image: BA219 flight path over Hudson Bay]

But on FR24 that path [is not there](https://www.flightradar24.com/BA219/10c5910f):

[image]

I've seen '[Why do aircraft on Flight Radar 24 jump around randomly sometimes?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2269)', since they are different services, what could be the reasons for FlightAware to behave like this? Also note the linked FR24 post is a different more jagged path than the one here.

FlightAware tracks from other flights show similar zigzags in the Hudson Bay area. Presumably this is just noisy tracking data. Any idea why that happens in this particular location?

Comment: Thanks, @Sanchises. I started with that question. The answer in that one is that the zigzag was a dogleg for congestion avoidance. I mention in my question that that seems less likely here since this flight was 3 hours from landing and maintaining an above-planned speed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do aircraft on Flight Radar 24 jump around randomly sometimes?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2269/why-do-aircraft-on-flight-radar-24-jump-around-randomly-sometimes)

Comment: @ymb1 - The zigzags I'm seeing with this flight on FlightAware look much more "believable" than the Flight Radar 24 discontinuities. These look like actual turns.

Comment: Looks fine on FR24: https://i.imgur.com/A16GiV3.png, so it's a FlightAware (tracking) issue like the 2nd linked post.

Comment: It sure does, @ymb1 ! That's even curiouser.

Comment: @NedGladstone - answer in 2nd link ;) If it helps, mark it so please :)

Comment: Since it's somewhat different (a possible FlightAware tracking problem that behaves quite differently than the FR24 issue), would it be better for you to create an "answer" that I can accept, @ymb1 ?

Comment: @NedGladstone - sure, why not, I've updated your question.

Comment: FlightAware tracks for other flights show similar zigzags in the Hudson Bay area. Presumably @ymb1 is right that it's a data issue and not the real flight path. I'm still curious why the data would get sketchy in that area.

Comment: Probably a rounding error/coordinates having a few digits cut off

Comment: I was also thrown off by the apparent smoothness. Perhaps FlightAware uses some kind of smoothing algorithm?

Comment: It does seem to be smoothing things. [The track log shows single entries for a course 150 degrees, from Edmonton Center.](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/BAW219/history/20180320/1140Z/EGLL/KDEN/tracklog) Later entries from Edmonton are better but still a bit wacky.

Comment: That sounds like the issue - a few wonky location points that are then connected with an artificially smoothed track. I can't +1 on comments, but presumably stackexchange would let me accept an answer if you add that as one.

Comment: @NedGladstone - see this: https://flightaware.com/about/faq#anomaly

Answer (score 3):

It looks as if the GPS location was only updated at intervals, and the software extrapolated the missing path information using bezier curves.

Comment: Even in that case, why would it assume it wasn't flying the original path? A Bezier can be a straight line if the control points are in a line, and in this case, they should be in a line.